# Surjective but not injective if and only if domain is strictly larger than co-domain

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

> For set $A$ having $n$ elements and set $B$ having $m$ elements, $n,m\in\mathbb{N}$, prove that $n < m$ if and only if $\exists \varphi:B \to A$, surjective but not injective.

Beginning with the assumption that $n < m$, suppose for contradiction that $\varphi$ is injective $\Longrightarrow \exists \varphi': B \to \varphi(B)$, bijective $(\dagger)$. We know that since $\varphi$ is surjective, $\varphi(B)=A$. For A having $n$ elements, this implies $\varphi(B)$ has $n$ elements and therefore $B$ has $n$ elements by $(\dagger)$, which is a contradiction.

Beginning with the assumption that $\varphi$ is surjective but not injective, suppose for contradiction that $n \geq m$. We know that for $a_1 \in A$, $\varphi^{-1}\{a_1\}$ is non-empty since $\varphi$ is surjective. Furthermore, for any $a_2 \in A$ such that $a_1 \neq a_2$, $\varphi^{-1}\{a_1\} \cap\varphi^{-1}\{a_2\} = \emptyset$ since $\varphi$ is not injective. From here, I'm not sure how to proceed.

Please let me know if I have made any mistakes to help me correct my proof. Thank you.

Comment: The proposition is trivally true for m = 1 (or 0 if 0 in N).  So preceed with induction on m.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For part two, assume $\phi$ is a non-injective surjection.
$\{ \psi^{-1}(x) : x \in A \}$ is a partition of B.
There are n not empty parts to the partition. 
As $\psi$ is not injective at least one of the partition
parts has more than one element.  Thus n < m.